# $promise stays promised on 'then' function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I'm using angular's `$resource` to perform a GET operation. This is how I do it:

```
var query = {customerid: $stateParams.customerid}    
$resource('api/reports/running_count').get(query).$promise.then(function(value) {
    $scope.runningInstance = value;
});
```

I also tried it like that:

```
$resource('api/reports/running_count').get(query, function(value) {
    $scope.runningInstance = value;
});
```

The request returns a number. I checked the response with chrome's developer-tools. The request is indeed sent as follows:

```
<base-url>/api/reports/running_count?customerid=<id>
```

The response returns a number, again as expected.

But when I put a breakpoint in the callback function, the `value` is again a promise and not a number. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The `$resource` service doesn't work when the response is a primative because it use angular.copy which ignores primatives.

Comment: @georgeawg - Thank you! That was indeed the problem. If you want, you can add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What @georgeawg said, also you can use regular `$http` for that pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$resource` service doesn't work when the response is a primative. It uses `angular.copy` to copy the data to the `$resource` object and `angular.copy` doesn't copy a primative to an object. It can only make deep copies of properties of other objects.

From the Docs:<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)</sup>

> ### angular.copy
>
> Creates a deep copy of `source`, which should be an object or an array.
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.
> - If `source` is not an object or array (inc. `null` and `undefined`), `source` is returned.

In your case the source was not an object and you were getting just the `$promise` property which the `$resource` service attaches to the resource object.

Answer (score 0):

From angular example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user, getResponseHeaders){
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save(function(user, putResponseHeaders) {
    //user => saved user object
    //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
  });
});
```

Just put you values there.

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure it answers my problem. Or at least I don't understand how it does that.

Comment: The answer was - try to use callback instead of promise.

Comment: I did try that. It appears in the original question and didn't work as well :/

Answer (score 0):

As far I know if you want to get data using `query value` then server get `query value` as a string. it is useful when you will send query from search box . for example want to search product by name or something else then you can use like.

in service:

```
var query = {productname: '123'}
getProducts: function(query) {
   var getProducts = $resource('/api/products', {}, {
       'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
       });
   return getProducts.get(query);
 }
```

and server side will receive as `req.query.productname` so productname as a `string` so you need to convert it to `number` if needed as number.

but if you want to find produt by `id` you should send `id` as a parameter not query for *exactly matching* that also may send as string.

for example in service:

```
getProductById: function(id) {
    var getProductById = $resource('/api/products/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
                    'get': {method: 'GET'}
     });
     return getProductById.get({id: id});
 }
```

so server side will receive as `req.params.id`

Comment: Actually, if you send an object to a get call, $resource converts it to query params. I don't want it to be path variable (like what you mentioned) because that's not the case. In the case I posted everything works well, the server gets the parameters as I would expect it to get them and send back the correct response. But on the return I get a promise object instead of the number that's returned.